# Corda performance tool - setting of multiple jmeter servers

Tags: jmeter, rmi, corda

I have setup a JMeter client and server , following the instructions in the [documentation](https://docs.corda.r3.com/performance-testing/running-jmeter-corda.html) .

I could successfully invoke transactions locally as well remotely .

Now I want to increase the number of JMeter servers

- added the server Ip and port in jmeter.properties
- made an entry in server rmi config file
- started the client
- When I start the server , it starts but does not refer to the rmi server config , in logs it says

  ```
  jmeter.Launcher$Companion.prepareJMeterArguments$jmeter - No rmi server mapping found, using default server.rmi.localport - assuming no ssh tunnelling in effect
  ```
- The command used to run server:

  ```
  java -jar jmeter-corda-4.0-capsule.jar -XjmeterProperties jmeter.properties  -XrverRmiMappings sample-server-rmi.config -- -s
  ```

Any config has to be modified? other then the remote_hosts and server rmi config file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to take a look at the jmeter page on the docs to double check whether any of the config options to see if any of them have changed. (https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/performance-testing/running-jmeter-corda.html#running-jmeter-corda)

So this is a feature that only works on corda enterprise and NOT on corda open source, if you're paying R3 for it you should have a contact for enterprise support that should be able to help you with the small stuff like this.

Worth mentioning as well that there's new releases of corda (now 4.5) so you might want to take a look at that as well to see if your issue has been fixed already.